# All attributes nil on 'Create' for Associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Not sure what I screwed up... can't create a library_hour that belongs_to a library_location. On submit, library_hour is nil for all attributes except the library_location_id.

**Routes**

```
resources :library_locations do
  resources :library_hours
end
```

#### Models

```
    class LibraryLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :library_hours
      has_many :library_contacts

      validates_presence_of :title, :image_thumbnail_url, :latitude, :longitude
      validates_uniqueness_of :title
     end

    class LibraryHour < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :library_location
      validates_associated :library_location

      validates_presence_of :day, :open_time, :close_time
      validates :day, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
      validates_inclusion_of :day, :in => 0..6
    end
```

#### LibraryHoursController

```
    before_filter :get_library_location

    def get_library_location
      @library_location = LibraryLocation.find(params[:library_location_id])
    end

    def create
      @library_hour = @library_location.library_hours.build(params[:library_location])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @library_hour.save
          format.html { redirect_to @library_location }
          format.json { render json: @library_hour }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @library_hour.errors }
        end
      end
    end
```

#### Form "/library_locations/:id/library_hours/new"

```
    <%= form_for([@library_location, @library_hour]) do |f| %>

      <%= f.select :day, Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index.collect { |day,i| [day,i] } %>

      <%= f.time_select :open_time, {:minute_step => 15, :ignore_date => true} %>

      <%= f.time_select :close_time, {:minute_step => 15, :ignore_date => true} %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :library_location %>

      <%= f.submit %>

    <% end %>
```

ERRORS: All attributes appear to be nil on submit:

```
5 errors prohibited this library_hour from being saved:

Day can't be blank
Day is not a number
Day is not included in the list
Open time can't be blank
Close time can't be blank
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help/suggestions.

### ADDED

**Rails Shell**

```
Started POST "/library_locations/110/library_hours" for....
Processing by LibraryHoursController#create as HTML
Parameters: 
  {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9x8fda9faj0q9e01=", "library_hour"=>
  {"day"=>"3", "open_time(4i)"=>"05", "open_time(5i)"=>"00", "close_time(4i)"=>"16",
  "close_time(5i)"=>"00", "library_location"=>"#<LibraryLocation:0x008fc24b46c7570>"},
  "commit"=>"Submit", "library_location_id"=>"110"}

LibraryLocation SELECT "library_locations".* 
FROM "library_locations"
WHERE "library_locations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "110"]]

begin transaction

LibraryLocation Load
SELECT "library_locations".* 
FROM "library_locations"
WHERE "library_locations"."id" = 110 LIMIT 1

LibraryLocation Exists
SELECT 1 FROM "library_locations" 
WHERE  ("library_locations"."title" = 'Test Library' 
  AND "library_locations"."id" != 110) LIMIT 1

rollback transaction
```

Comment: Can you tell me where you have mentioned the url that form gets submitted to?

Comment: VenkatK, POST "/library_locations/15/library_hours"

Comment: Better idea is to try this all with rails console. If association works properly in console then it should work with form too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the attributes of LibraryHour to be attr_accessible.

```
class LibraryHour
    attr_accessible :day, :open_time, etc
end
```

Otherwise you can't mass assign the attributes using build.

Comment: Fiona, thank you for your response. I have not created the User model yet... perhaps this is the underlying issue? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I meant declare the attribute of LibraryHour.

Comment: Once I added this, I only had to remove the ":ignore_date => true" on the time fields, and it worked! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change these lines in controller and view:

```
@library_hour = @library_location.library_hours.build(params[:library_hour])
```

and

```
<%= form_for(@library_hour, :url => [@library_location, @library_hour]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it didn't work. The comment below makes me think it could be because I have not created the user model yet... Is that going to be an issue? :/